# Error creating Windows Azure BizTalk Service instance

Tags: azure, biztalk

After yesterday's announcement of BizTalk Service GA on Windows Azure, I'm trying to create a new Development instance so I can start migrating my on premises BizTalk projects to there.

After I fill the wizard and start waiting for the instance creation, I get the following error:

> Could not connect to the Tracking Database. Confirm that the SQL Database details are correct and that Windows Azure Services is enabled on the SQL Database. (RDFE - Operation ID = fcc014e60cea345c9e03dcd2dca787d3 )

What is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure DB allows Azure services to access it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the internal DNS problems are affecting it.

The Register [Microsoft pulls its crowd-control tech from out of the shadows](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/11/23/windows_azure_load_balancing/)

> a variety of Microsoft services including Windows Azure and Xbox became unavailable due to an as-yet-unspecified problem with Microsoft's global DNS configuration

or

[Xbox One site BELLY-UP in GLOBAL Microsoft cloud catastrophe](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/11/21/azure_blips_offline_again/)

> Initial reports seem to indicate the problem stems from an internal DNS issue, as both the page and various Azure services are throwing DNS errors. Azure may be working, but reaching it is difficult.

Comment: Well, if this is the problem, we are screwed with no solution right?

Comment: I would say so.  I would ask Microsoft to look at the issue as either there is a problem with their template, in either case something they need to address.